# fileupload name is not working

Tags: javascript, html

Fileupload is working from this code i am copy from this link http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/javascript/#fileinput ,for me what problem means selecting file means not showing the file name in that box,i did not add any extra line code

```
<div class="fileinput fileinput-new input-group" data-provides="fileinput">
<div class="form-control" data-trigger="fileinput"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file fileinput-exists"></i> <span class="fileinput-filename"></span></div>
<span class="input-group-addon btn btn-default btn-file"><span class="fileinput-new">Select file</span><span class="fileinput-exists">Change</span><input type="file" name="..."></span>
<a href="#" class="input-group-addon btn btn-default fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput">Remove</a>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry can you explain your problem in detail or in other words.

Comment: Did you `<link>` to the `fileinput.js` provided in your website?